# How to get the value that return from the javascript function?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the value of a function after the result of an ajax call has come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550002/how-to-return-the-value-of-a-function-after-the-result-of-an-ajax-call-has-come)

I have one function that use to count the quantity of item in my controller.

```
function GetQtyItem() {
  var qty;
  var urlQuantity = "Quotation/CountQuantity";
  $.getJSON(urlQuantity, function (quantity) {
      qty = quantity.ja;
  });
  alert(qty); //3
  return qty;
}
```

I included the file name with the correct part, and called this function in another view of my asp.net mvc project :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var i = GetQtyItem();
  alert(i);
</script>
```

But the result in the alert dialog is `Undefined`.

Could any one tell me, how can I alert it with the correct value(3). Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So you got two alerts, the first with 3 and the second undefined?

Comment: No, Satya. The first alert is undefined, and the second alert is 3.

Comment: That's the problem. Your function is defined after it is called. Put the function definition before the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.getJSON is an AJAX request... which takes time.  You must wait for the data to come back, and then alert the result.

Try this:

```
var qty, i;
function GetQtyItem() {
  var urlQuantity = "Quotation/CountQuantity";
  return $.getJSON(urlQuantity, function (quantity) {
      qty = quantity.ja;
      alert('Request is done');
  });
}

i = GetQtyItem();
i.done(function() {
  alert("Quantity is " + qty);
});
```